# How to combine numbers from 2 different arrays into just one array?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, random, arduino, arduino-c++

I have a code in which I am generating random number of Colums = numCols and random number of Rows = numRows. The multiple of nomRows and numCols = numCells. I want to color each of the Cell by a different color, I know the total number of Cells I have, because that is numCells. Therefore I have an array "colors", which has 6 values. Every number in that array represents and how many times I have that color in that array. I have a loop which generates a randomm number for each color, but always making sure the total of the numbers in the array is never larger then NumCells. You cant have total 23 values for color and only 10 cells to fit it into. Now this works fine, the total amout of number in the array is never bigger than numCells.

So I have an array colors[] which contains 6 numbers, I want to push that array into mysound2[] and after I push it create a nother loop which will add 2 more numbers into that array to end up with an array mysound2[] which containts total number of 8 numbers.

But I can't get it working, either I get an error: invalid types 'int [8][int [6]]' for array subscript Which I guess arduino is not happt that into array of 8 I am only trying to add 6 numbers.

Or if I try something else the code generates 0,0,0.

Please how can I push colors[] into mysoun2[] and add 2 more random numbers?

````
// CODE FOR COLORS
``` int AnalogPin0 = A0; //Declare an integer variable, hooked up to analog pin 0
``` int AnalogPin1 = A1; //Declare an integer variable, hooked up to analog pin 1

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //Begin Serial Communication with a baud rate of 9600
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));

}

void loop() {
// 1)Gray, 2)White, 3)Yellow, 4)Blue, 5)Black, 6)Red

int numCols1  = random(1,4);
int numCols2  = random(2,5);
int numCols   = numCols1 + numCols2;

int numRows1  = random(2,5);
int numRows2  = random(2,6);
int numRows   = numRows1 + numRows2;

int numCells  = numCols * numRows;
int colors[]  = {5,3,2,1,0,0};
int numAlloc  = colors[0] + colors[1] + colors[2] + colors[3] + colors[4] + colors[5];


for (int i=0; i<numCells - numAlloc; i++)
{
  int color = random(0,7);
  color[colors]++;
}



  /*The Serial.print() function does not execute a "return" or a space
      Also, the "," character is essential for parsing the values,
      The comma is not necessary after the last variable.*/
Serial.print(colors [0]);     
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(numCols);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(numRows);
Serial.print(",");
//Serial.print(numCells);
//Serial.print(",");
Serial.println();
delay(5000); // For illustration purposes only. This will slow down your program if not removed 
}


//CODE FOR ADDING 8 NUMBERS INTO ONE ARRAY WITH 2 LOOPS
# define Parameters 8
int mysound2[Parameters];
int randNumber =0;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
     randomSeed(analogRead(0));
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < Parameters-2; thisPin++)  {

    randNumber = random(1, 100); // generates between 0 and 127

    mysound2[thisPin]= randNumber;   

  }
    for (int thisPin = Parameters-2; thisPin < Parameters; thisPin++)  {

    randNumber = random(100, 200); // generates between 0 and 127

    mysound2[thisPin]= randNumber;   

  }
}

void loop() {
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < Parameters; thisPin++)  {
     Serial.println(mysound2[thisPin]);  
     delay(5000);
}
}


//ME TRYING TO COMBINE THE TWO CODES
// 1)Gray, 2)White, 3)Yellow, 4)Blue, 5)Black, 6)Red

# define Parameters 8

int numCols1  = random(1,4);
int numCols2  = random(2,5);
int numCols   = numCols1 + numCols2;

int numRows1  = random(2,5);
int numRows2  = random(2,6);
int numRows   = numRows1 + numRows2;

int numCells  = numCols * numRows;
int colors[]  = {5,3,2,1,0,0};
int numAlloc  = colors[0] + colors[1] + colors[2] + colors[3] + colors[4] + colors[5];
int color     = 0;

int mysound1[Parameters];
int randNumber1 =0;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
     randomSeed(analogRead(0));
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < Parameters-2; thisPin++)  
    {
      for (int i=0; i<numCells - numAlloc; i++)
      {
        int color = random(0,6);
        color[colors]++;
        }
       mysound1[color];
      }

  for (int thisPin = Parameters-2; thisPin < Parameters; thisPin++)  {

    randNumber1 = random(100, 200); // generates between 0 and 127

    mysound1[thisPin]= randNumber1;   
  }
}

void loop() {
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < Parameters; thisPin++)  {
     Serial.println(mysound1[color]);  
     delay(2000);
    }
}
````

Comment: The only obvious problem I'm finding is that in several places, you use `color[colors]` instead of `colors[color]`. `color` is declared as an `int` and `colors` is declared as an array of `int`s.

Comment: Oh good catch, however even if I change that. And the state `mysound1[colors];`
Which I have hoped would push the 6 numbers into that array. I still get this error:
invalid types 'int [8][int [6]]' for array subscript.
I understand that Arduino doesnt like I am only trying to push 6 number where 8 number should be. But then I thought I took care of this in the first for loop by declaring this:
`for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < Parameters-2; thisPin++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to copy an array into another array. You can do that with a function like this:

```cpp
void copyArray(int* source, int* destination, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        *destination++ = *source++;
    }
}
```

So, if you want to copy 6 elements in `colors` into `mysound2`, 
`copyArray(colors, mysound2, 6);` would do it.

If you want to add 2 more elements, just do something like this.

```cpp
mysound2[6] = randNumber1;
mysound2[7] = randNumber2;
```

**Edit:** In the comment section, you mentioned that you want to combine two arrays into one. A function like this would do that.

```cpp
void copyArray(int* source, int* destination, int destStartIndex, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        destination[destStartIndex + i] = *source++;
    }
}
```

The code below will copy `colors` to the first 6 bytes of `mysound2` and copy `thisPin` to the following 2 bytes of `mysound2`.

```
copyArray(colors, mysound2, 0, 6);
copyArray(thisPin, mysound2, 6, 2);
```

Comment: I have not described my proble correctly. I have an array `mysound2[]` which should have 8 numbers in total. I have an array `colors[]` which has 6 number. After I push those 6 into `mysound2[]` I have to create 2 more random numbers to add to this array, so it in total has 8. I tried that with a for loop, or it can be a second array, which produces those two numbers, don't care. Just can't figure out how to combine them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I managed to get it working!